# Crash exiting native code

Tags: android, java-native-interface

What is the cause of this `A/libc: invalid address or address of corrupt block 0x5da90aa0 passed to dlfree` and `A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadbaad (code=1), thread 19239 (IntentService[K)` **intermitent** crash?

The C++ code appears to be triggering the crash.  No exceptions are catchable from Java-land.  The crash is observed intermittently on Android 4.4.4.  I have not observed it on Android 6.0.

Code of native entry/exit point:

```
JNIEXPORT jstring
JNICALL Java_com_company_product_ClassJNI_foo(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj, jstring options)
{
   const jsize        optionLength = env->GetStringUTFLength(options);
   std::vector <char> optionsBuffer(static_cast<int>(optionLength));
   env->GetStringUTFRegion(options, 0, optionLength, optionsBuffer.data());
   const std::string nativeOptions(optionsBuffer.cbegin(), optionsBuffer.cend());

   try
   {
      SerialWrapper si(env, obj);
      const std::string result = Procedure::exec(nativeOptions, si);

      // gets this far

      return env->NewStringUTF(result.c_str());
   }
   catch (const JObjectError& e)
   {
      const JSON jsonError{{PROP_ERROR, std::string(e.what())}};
      return env->NewStringUTF(jsonError.dump().c_str());
   }
}
```

I have read seemingly related posts discuss multiple threads accessing a resource and I do not believe that to be the issue here.

Comment: Is your return call really in the `catch` block?  What does your function return if there's no exception?  That's quite likely to cause a crash.

Answer (score 0):

I was not managing the native string resources correctly in the first few lines:

```
// problematic
const jsize        optionLength = env->GetStringUTFLength(options);
std::vector <char> optionsBuffer(static_cast<int>(optionLength));
env->GetStringUTFRegion(options, 0, optionLength, optionsBuffer.data());
const std::string nativeOptions(optionsBuffer.cbegin(), optionsBuffer.cend());
```

and when cleanup occurred on native exit, improper freeing occured.

After creating/using this utility function:

```
std::string createStdString(JNIEnv& env, jstring& javaString)
{
   // appears to work
   const char* rawString = env.GetStringUTFChars(javaString, nullptr);
   const std::string nativeString(rawString);
   env.ReleaseStringUTFChars(javaString, rawString);
   return nativeString;
}
```

I have not observed a crash.

This post was useful: https://community.oracle.com/thread/1549127